# Existence of set

Tags: real-analysis

Problem: Show that the following limit always exists:

Let $f:\mathbb{R}^+ \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$

$$\lim_{r \to 0}\inf \{ f(x): 0<x<r\}$$

This doesn't seem right to me, consider

$f(x)= \log x$, then $\inf \{f(x): 0<x<r\}=-\infty$ and so the limit does not exist. Am I missing something?

Comment: If $g(r):=\text{inf} \{ f(x): 0<x<r\} $ and $g(r)\in \mathbb{R}$ for at least one element $r$, then g  is 
 well-defined and decreasing in $(0,\infty )$ and $\lim_{r\to r_0} g(r) $ exists for every $r_0\in (0,\infty )$. But if $f=lon(x)$ g is not defined for any element . so $g$ isn't defined.

Comment: *limit always exists* --- It is fairly standard, when considering the extreme limits $\liminf$ and $\limsup,$ to consider their values in the extended real number line. Look in the book's text discussion before this problem (or class notes, or wherever you saw this problem), and I suspect you'll find this concern taken care of.